# bootstrap css and javascript doesn't work in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

In my new rails project, I add bootstrap css and javascript; but it doesn't work and class aren't add to pages.

I copy files in `app/assets/javascripts` and `app/assets/stylesheets`.

I add this file in `application.html.erb` like below:

```
<head>
  <title>JiraAjax</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application' %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'bootstrap.min' %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'bootstrap.min' %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
```

when I run project, I see both of file in html code in browser, but class aren't preview and doesn't work.

Other css is working, but bootstrap doesn't work.

I added pre-compile line for each file in `application.rb`, but the problem isn't solve.

`app/assets/javascripts/application.js`:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap.min
```

`app/assets/stylesheets/application.css`:

```
 *= require_self
 *= require bootstrap-rtl.min
```

It's very strange for me, any one can help me?

Comment: What's the generated HTML source code? And can you open the css/js soude code via click the hyperlink in the HTML source code? and in this case, should have 'app/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css' and 'app/assets/javascripts/bootstrap.min.js' files in the corresponding folders.

Comment: Yes, I can open css/js soure code via click the hyperlink and copy files in correct path.

Comment: That sounds like the asset pipleline is not including them, what does your manifest look like? Do you have an application.css and application.js file? If so what is in them?

Comment: Yes, project have application.css and application.js. I add both of theme in question.

Answer (score 0):

You have to watch out for the load order of the assets that you're using. Depending on the specific situation, bootstrap should be loaded either before or after other assets.

Another issue I ran into was having either asset twice, which threw me off.

I'd suggest playing around with the order and making sure you don't have duplicate imports :) What I ended up doing was just hardcoding imports into my html.erb files instead of dealing with the asset-pipeline as a temporary workaround.